# subprocess.Popen makes terminal crash after KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I wrote a simple python script `./vader-shell` which uses subprocess.Popen to launch a spark-shell and I have to deal with KeyboardInterrupt, since otherwise the child process would not die

```
command = ['/opt/spark/current23/bin/spark-shell']
command.extend(params)

p = subprocess.Popen(command)

try:
  p.communicate()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  p.terminate()
```

This is what I see with `ps f`

[image]

When I actually interrupt with ctrl-C, I see the processes dying (most of the time). However the terminal starts acting weird: I don't see any cursor, and all the lines starts to appear randomly

[image]

I am really lost in what is the best way to run a subprocess with this library and how to handle killing of the child processes. What I want to achieve is basic: whenever my python process is killed with a ctrl-C, I want all the family of process being killed. I googled several solutions `os.kill`, `p.wait()` after termination, calling `subprocess.Popen(['reset'])` after termination but none of them worked.
Do you know what is the best way to kill when KeyboardInterrupt happens? Or do you know any other more reliable library to use to spin-up processes?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing blatantly wrong with your code, the problem is that the command you are launching tries to do stuff with the current terminal, and does not correctly restore the settings where shutting down. Replacing your command with a "sleep" like below  will run just fine and stop on Ctrl+C without problems:

```
import subprocess

command = ['/bin/bash']
command.extend(['-c', 'sleep 600'])

p = subprocess.Popen(command)

try:
  p.communicate()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  p.terminate()
```

I don't know what you're trying to do with spark-shell, but if you don't need it's output you could try to redirect it to /dev/null so that it's doesn't mess up the terminal display:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```